# Migrate Heroku app from bamboo stack to cedar stack

Tags: heroku

How do I migrate my Heroku app from the bamboo stack to the cedar stack?

I'm trying to follow this guide https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler

but when I try `git push heroku master` it just says

> Everything up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

Try following [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration) article instead. (I'm assuming you're running a Rails app.)